# Select proper selectedItemtext when selectedItemValue is same for multiple SelectedItemText in dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dropdown and binding values from database and values like below.

### Value         Text

AP          AndraPradesh
BL           Bangalore
KL           Kerala
AP           ArunaChalPradesh

When I select ArunaChalPradesh By default AndraPradesh is selecting back again.

Answer (score 2):

Value fields for a dropdown list should be unique.  Since they are generally not displayed, I'd say it'd be a good idea to change the value fields to be an ID of some sort instead of abbreviations of the Text.

Since you are trying to set the selected value to AP, it is grabbing the first value from the dropdown list.

If you are sticking with the abbreviations, just change the 2nd AP to another unique value (maybe AC?)